# Couldn't establish postgres connection with Wordpress using Docker Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

There is not this kind of question including docker-compose.

I couldn't find what is the problem with my docker-compose.yml file.
By the way, I don't want to use ready "wp-postgres" image on the docker hub.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB_NAME: exampledb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: examplepass
      POSTGRES_DB_USER: exampleuser
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgres

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

Here is the logs:

```
dpress_1  | WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
wordpress_1  | Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
wordpress_1  | [02-Mar-2020 18:33:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'db'
wordpress_1  |   continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results)
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.25.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.25.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress_1  | [Mon Mar 02 18:33:38.074477 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.3.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
wordpress_1  | [Mon Mar 02 18:33:38.074510 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
db_1         |
db_1         | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1         |
db_1         | 2020-03-02 19:40:34.511 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1         | 2020-03-02 19:40:34.512 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1         | 2020-03-02 19:40:34.512 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
```

Comment: Your postgres instance is up and accepting connections? Check the logs with `docker logs <db container id or name>`

Comment: OK. I update the question. Added the logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a PostgreSQL database with the official Wordpress image.  You'll see in your log:

```
wordpress_1  | [02-Mar-2020 18:33:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
```

The official Wordpress image assumes a mysql database, and unfortunately does not provide any additional configurables to change it.  If you want to use Postgres, you'll need to use the `wp-postgres` image, or use this modified version of the official Wordpress image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/ntninja/wordpress-postgresql

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)

Answer (score 1):

The official Wordpress image doesn't support PostgreSQL as a database, you have to use MySQL or MariaDB.

There are unofficial WP forks that adds postgres support but their stability is unknown.